# Centering a Div Both Horizontally And Vertically

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a HTML like:

```
<div class='number'><div class='n'><span>1</span></div></div>
```

Now, I'd like center it like image below. How can I do it?

Jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Arxcm/1/)

[image]

Comment: Post jsfiddle or something,please

Comment: @Notulysses: just updated

Comment: You have not added css classes

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YvV8S/. If it's not what you want then be more specific.

Comment: @j08691: not good method

Comment: @user2728514 - excuse me? You have nothing, I give you something, and then you criticize my code? Buzz off.

Comment: @j08691:sorry for this. thank you for helping me but it is actual not good solution.

Comment: Explain what about it "is actual not good solution".

Comment: from my point of view. it is not good : .n span {top:15px;}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/7sRJN/)**</kbd>

```
.number {
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}
.n {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, here you can find some tricks for vertical alignment in css. http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/
There are quite a few things that you could try, not just for this case but for future cases. I wish it helps you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your number CSS class:

```
.number{
background:green;
text-align:center;   
width:70px;
line-height:70px; 
height:70px; 
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-o-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.number .n{width:40px; 
height:40px; 
vertical-align:baseline; 
line-height:40px; 
margin:0 auto; 
border-radius:50%; 
background:#e54e53;
display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Arxcm/4/